How can I build statements using CockroachDB's `AS OF SYSTEM TIME` clause with knex?
I have been able to work around this with some fromRaw and joinRaw shenanigans, but the joinRaw in particular is rather unfortunate (having to specify the full join in raw just to add the clause at the end).
For example, the following works, but is there a better way?
await knex('table')
.joinRaw('INNER JOIN "other" ON "table"."id" = "other"."tableId" ... AS OF SYSTEM TIME follower_read_timestamp()')
.where(...)
.et_cetera(...)

